# Sum of Product and Product of sum for (AB+C)(B+C'D)'?

Tags: proof-verification, boolean-algebra

I am having a little trouble trying to converting the expression into sum-of-products and product-of-sums form. Not sure if i am doing the expression correctly. But this was what i was able to do.

I started out using Demorgan law:

**(AB+C)(B+C'D)'**

what i did was:

**(AB+C)(B+C'D)'**

**(AB+C) (B'(C+D'))**

**(AB+C) (B'C+B'D')**

**ABB'C +ABB'D'+CB'C+CB'D'**

**B'C+CB'D'**

Are my steps correct?

Comment: What are the apostrophes supposed to be? Derivatives? Regular expressions?

Comment: @RushabhMehta Complements I guess (tag boolean-algebra).

Comment: @RushabhMehta there complements

Comment: @paulplusx well my attempt was trying get the SOP

Comment: They are negations of the propositions: $B'$ means "not B".

Comment: @amWhy i am using demorgan law

Comment: Yes, indeed you are, and your work is fine, thus far.  See my answer.

Comment: It is just a different question, @paulplusx, that sought to find the SOP and POS of a *different* proposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is correct thus far: You can go further:

$\begin{align} 
B'C+CB'D'& = B'C(1)+B'CD'\\
&=B'C(1+D')\\ 
& = B'C(1) \\ 
&= B'C
\end{align}$

This is now in both SOP and POS form.

Comment: ok thank you i really needed the feedback @amWhy